# Uninstalling JRE but .msi is missing

Tags: windows-10, java, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall an old Java Runtime Environment (Java 8 Update 101 / 8.0.1010.13) from a Windows 10 client machine.

It seems, that the original installer is missing, so it prompts me to enter a path to **jre1.8.0_101full.msi**.

I can't find that file on that machine, neither on the internet. I already tried the Oracle Java archive page. jre-8u101-windows-i586.exe seems to be the right version, but I can't install it.

How do I uninstall it anyway? Can I somehow extract the .msi from the .exe?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Please edit your question in order to clarify it.

Comment: I assume you have downloaded the `jre-8u101-windows-i586.exe` and `jre-8u101-windows-x64.exe` and attempted to use that. I am 99.99% positive that the .msi is contained in the executable

Comment: Open application control panel from Win+R > `appwiz.cpl`. Then uninstall from there.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, jre-8u101-windows-i586.exe seems to be the right file, but I can't install it. How do I extract the .msi from the .exe?

Comment: @Biswapriyo That's what I'm trying, but it is asking me for the path to that .msi I don't have...

Comment: Can you be a little more specific then "i can't install it"?  You should be able to extract the contents of the executable, even if the installation fails, the extract.MSI contained within the executable if I am correct should stick around until you clear your temporary files.

Comment: The name of the .msi was a little different and it (and the directory that contained it) got deleted directly after closing the installer. But you got me on the right direction (see the answer), thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I got it:

1. Downloaded and started jre-8u101-windows-i586.exe
2. The Install failed in the second step with an error code, but as long as the installer is still open I could find a jre1.8.0_101.msi where the uninstall process searches for jre1.8.0_101full.msi (notice the difference in name)
3. Copied the file to a different directory and renamed it jre1.8.0_101full.msi
4. Closed the installer (directory and jre1.8.0_101.msi get deleted)
5. Started the uninstall process and changed the path to my new directory.

Thanks @Biswapriyo for your help!

Comment: How did you find the .msi file? is it generated right there at the location of the .exe file? I tried to look but couldn't find that .msi file anywhere.

Comment: In some temporary folder the installer created. I found by searching via `dir /s jre*.msi`

Comment: 2021 update: JFYI, to download Oracle JDK and JRE installers, you now have to create an Oracle account. I was able to just "reinstall" with the downloaded installer (make sure you choose JRE or JDK correctly). After that, the "Uninstall" option from control panel did not ask for the location of `.msi` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today while attempting to uninstall Java 8 Update 211 (on Windows 10 Home edition, version 1803).

Previous answers in this thread prompted me to end-up at an Oracle page including the title "Java SE 8 Archive Downloads (JDK 8u211 and later)" and find that the relevant filename for me was jre-8u211-windows-i586-iftw.exe (which I found on another site in order to avoid registering with Oracle).  I downloaded that file, double-clicked on it, made an unsuccessful try, then double clicked on it again and "installed" the software, then uninstalled after the installation had completed.  Java then no longer appeared as installed in the list under "Programs and Features".